# identifying colors in javaCV

Tags: java, javacv

I'm trying to use javaCV to identify objects' color using webcam and make a NXT mobile robot to do a particular task based on the detected color object.

I'm having trouble to identify colors of objects.
(basically, I want to differentiate between blue and red, and print out the color detected.)

can anyone help me ? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating `BufferedImage` from the capture, and the getting each pixels RGB. Once you are at that point, just use these functions to get the RGB values.

```
public static int getAlpha(int rgb) {
    return (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF;
}

public static int getRed(int rgb) {
    return (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

public static int getGreen(int rgb) {
    return (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

public static int getBlue(int rgb) {
    return rgb & 0xFF;
}
```